# Android : alternative to setVisibility to Display images onscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility

First of all, I am very new at Android and teaching myself so I am not asking you to code it for me.  Just give me some terms, topics or a subject to study and I will hit the books and figure it out.

I am making an app where the user sets what appears on screen by pressing a button or selecting an image.  The only way I know how to do this is to have an onClickListener set a variable and use a switch statement to display an imageView that corresponds to the variable selected.

example:

```
    //on click listeners set variable userPic1 and userPic2

    switch(userPic1){
    case 1:
        pic11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic14.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 2:
        pic11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic14.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 3:
        pic11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic14.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 4:
        pic11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic14.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    }


    switch(userPic2){
    case 1:
        pic21.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic22.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic23.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic24.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 2:
        pic21.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic22.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic23.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic24.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 3:
        pic21.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic22.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic23.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pic24.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case 4:
        pic21.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic22.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic23.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pic24.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    }       
}
```

I feel like there is probably a better way to code this, but the bigger problem is in my XML layouts. I have all of these imageViews stacked on top of each other and it is getting difficult to see how they will look because it's just a mess.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the help I have been testing out viewFlipper and using arrays and think both will work through out my app a lot better then my original code.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html will make this a bit easier for you to manage, without such unruly code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ViewFlipper` as suggested may help if you're trying to switch between many views. However, if you're really just changing the image and don't need to change your layout instead of creating lots of views, I would simply just set the image on your `ImageView` (I'm assuming picXX are `ImageViews`). You can store your IDs in an array or two and get them from there. Something like:

```
int[] userPics1 = new int[] {R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, ... }
```

and then:

```
ImageView pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pic);
pic.setImageResource(userPics1[userPic1]);
```